# Get the position of Button in List View

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I have one problem.

I want to get the position of `Button` in `List View`.

In below image when I clicked in Edit or Delete button i just want its position in `List View`.

How it possible?

This is my Office Management Screen. All the data getting in `ListView` run-time from my web-service.

[image: This is my Office Management Screen. All the data getting run-time from my web-service.]

I get the data in List View by using this code-

---

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Office_Mgmt.this, officeList, R.layout.office_mgmt_list_model, new String[] { "office_name" }, new int[] { R.id.label}); 

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you can use `setTag` for setting position to your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom adapter, passing the context of your app as argument to set the click:

```
listView.setAdapter(new PesquisaAdapter(this, anunciantescidades, this);
```

Then, in the constructor of your adapter you will have a `OnClickListener` to recieve the argument `this` you passed:

```
public PesquisaAdapter(Context context, List<Anunciante> anunciantes, OnClickListener onClick1)
```

In the getView method of the adapter, you can set onClickListener of the button:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
    Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClick1);
}
```

In your java, you can implements `onClickListener`, and then do  what you want with your button:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(yourbutton.getId() == v.getId()){                
        final int position = listView.getPositionForView((LinearLayout)v.getParent());
    }
}
```

So, you will have the position in the list that you clicked, and you can manage the click of the edit and delete separately.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello sir, my List-View is in office_management.xml and the Edit and Delete Buttons are in office_mgmt_list.xms. So i can't create OnClickListener for Buttons in my java file.

Comment: `final int position = listview1.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());`

Answer (score 0):

implement `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` for the listview. 
Position and view can be identified from the handler. You can set additional info using setTag while creating the view inside the Adapter's getView method and retrieve in the handler and then verify in the handler if required.

Comment: But when I clicked on on Edit or Delete Button is it working?

Comment: do you mean whether it will work if you click on edit ? If so yes

Comment: Hello sir when i create OnItemClick() on ListView and i click on Delete or Edit button it occurs NullPointerException.

Comment: `final int position = listview1.getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());`